# What does pprof -call_tree do?

Tags: go, profiling, pprof

`go tool pprof` has a `-call_tree` option that, according to `-help`, should “Create a context-sensitive call tree”. However, `pprof -tree` on a CPU profile gives me the exact same output with and without this option. It looks like this (one representative node):

```
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%   calls calls% + context          
----------------------------------------------------------+-------------
                                             0.07s 35.00% |   google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.(*http2Server).operateHeaders
                                             0.04s 20.00% |   golang.org/x/net/http2.(*Framer).readMetaFrame
                                             0.02s 10.00% |   github.com/Shopify/sarama.(*FetchResponse).decode
     0.06s  0.79% 51.18%      0.20s  2.63%                | runtime.mapassign_faststr
                                             0.05s 25.00% |   runtime.newobject (inline)
                                             0.03s 15.00% |   aeshashbody
                                             0.03s 15.00% |   runtime.mallocgc
```

This is clearly not a tree, not least because it shows Sarama under HTTP/2 — consuming from Kafka (via Sarama) and serving HTTP/2 are two independent things this process does concurrently.

Why doesn’t `-call_tree` affect this output of `-tree`? In general, what does `-call_tree` do?

#### Extra credit

What is the exact meaning of the output node I showed above? Does it mean that 35% of samples containing `mapassign_faststr` also contained `operateHeaders` somewhere up the stack, and 10% contained `decode`? What about the lines below, such as `mallocgc`?

What documents could I read to answer the above questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn’t -call_tree affect this output of -tree

I think the `-call_tree` option doesn't change the output of `-tree` the outputs are not actually a tree, it outputs the nodes of the tree(more on this in the extra credit section).

---

> In general, what does -call_tree do?

You can see a difference when you take a look at images generated with the `-png` flag, without the `-call_tree` flag:
[image]
And with the `-call_tree` flag:
[image]

So instead of having 1 call tree, pprof attempts to create seperate trees based on context. In my case(will list them since the text on the image is not readable) the roots are:

- `testing.(*B).launch` (benchmark/test framework)
- `runtime.gcBgMarkWorker` (part of the runtime GC)
- `runtime.bgsweep` (part of the runtime GC)
- `runtime.mcall` (part of the runtime scheduler)
- `runtime.morestack` (something to do with the stack :)   )

In the non `-call_tree` image these nodes are still present, but start mid tree, as if our code calls these background processed directly.

Basically basically what the option does is remove/hide infrequent calls between functions, so you will end up with a tree for each set of functions that call each other frequently.

I haven't tested this but I imagine that pprof will do this context aware tree separation for user code as well. All in all it returns a subjectively more readable tree, or at least a more relevant one.

---

> What is the exact meaning of the output node I showed above?

The `-tree` option attempts to output the tree, as shows in the images. But since it is text output it shows you 1 node of the tree at a time, the non indented line in the `context` column is the current node, the rows above are nodes that call the current node, the rows below the nodes which this one calls (the arrows in the image).

The `calls%` is a the ["weight"](https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/master/internal/graph/graph.go#L253) of the the incoming or outgoing edge, so indeed the percentage of calls from or to a function.

---

> What documents could I read to answer the above questions?

If figured all of this out by looking at the source code, here are some key parts, in case you are interested:

- The file which does most of the output generation: https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/2007db6d4f53c44a417ddae675d50f56b8e8c2fd/internal/report/report.go
- The function for the `-tree` option: https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/2007db6d4f53c44a417ddae675d50f56b8e8c2fd/internal/report/report.go#L1047
- Line which explains when `-call_tree` is actually used: https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/2007db6d4f53c44a417ddae675d50f56b8e8c2fd/internal/report/report.go#L133